# OutOfMemory when uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, plupload

My code:

```
int chunk = Request["chunk"] != null ? int.Parse(Request["chunk"]) : 0;
string fileName = Request["name"] != null ? Request["name"] : string.Empty;
Response.Write(Request.Files.Count);
HttpPostedFile fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploaded-files");
if (Request.QueryString["originals"] == "yes")
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

I get an 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error.

My machine has 4 gigs of RAM. The file in question is approximately 1 GB. I am using plUpload to do the upload.

I've Enabled the 3GB switch. No difference. I have lots of RAM available, why am I running out of memory? Is there an alternative approach that uses less memory?

Comment: Read and write it in chunks instead of all at once?

Comment: Try compiling for x64 platform target.

Comment: Have you messed with your httpRuntime settings in config?  HttpPostedFile should buffer to disk when over 256KB, unless you've upped requestLengthDiskThreshold.

Comment: <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000" />

Comment: I'm going to look into chunk uploading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative implementation would be to use [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on HttpPostedFile:

```
fileUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName));
```

Comment: Excellent! This does the trick, I'm still going to look into chunk uploading, but for now this works!